# Visual Studio executable run twice

Tags: visual-studio-2010, executable, windows-7-x64

I have a problem with my computer : windows 7-64, freshly and cleanly reinstalled.

When I develop on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1, once the application is built, it runs twice.

Let me explain.

If I double clic on it in the folder, the console application runs, block for a few seconds (depending of the complexity of the program), then closes, the re-opens, runs and is stable.

If I launch it in a console, another console opens (like a pop up), runs the program, closes, then the program is executed in the first console.

If I launch it in debut with a break point, the application opens in a first console, executes without stopping, then closes, the relaunch in another console, et stop at the break point.

However, if I try other command non related to Visual Studio built (as firefox ...) I don't have this problem.

I've tried with a simple "Hello World" or with much more complex program, and I always get the same result.

Does anyone have already seen this kind of thing or now where to dig ?

Thank you.

Grégoire

Answer (score 28):

I've had this same problem recently, mine was solved by disabling Avast DeepScreen (if you use avast go into settings -> antivirus -> un-check DeepScreen). Hope that helps.

Comment: Avast moves on, I have had to put a folder exclusion in place on my projects folder, hope that helps anyone else getting this odd behaviour.

Comment: Thanks!! To expand on @SerhiiKuzmychov 's comment, it's now in Settings > General > Uncheck "Enable CyberCapture"

Comment: Update: It's still called CyberCapture but now it's in Settings > Protection > Core Shields. Or just go to Settings and type 'CyberCapture' into Search field (currently in upper right corner)

Answer (score 2):

They updated the settings page, you now have to uncheck CyperCapture under the 'General' tab.

Alternative you can add your program to 'Exclusions'.

Answer (score 2):

Updating Neller's answer. In my case it was also Avast, but today the option you need to disable is called "Cyber Capture"

Press the Hamburger to open the menu => Settings => Protection tab => Core Shields => uncheck "Enable CyberCapture"

Answer (score 1):

To expnad Neller's answer, this behaviour is common in various Antivirus Systems. More precisely I have come across it both on AVG and Avast.
To avoid this behaviour you can simply add a folder scan exception  regarding Visual Studio Folder.

e.g for AVG:

> Mennu -> Settings -> Exceptions -> Add:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0*